# Is "monitor" the synonym of "lock"/"bolt"?

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

In the JavaDoc, we can read several times the word "monitor" in Object:wait and Object:notify.

It seems to be used as a synonym of "verrou" (in French), or "lock"/"bolt" in English.

Is it true ?
Thank you.

Comment: In computer science **monitor** is indeed an unit allowing single entry to by the monitor guarded code pieces. See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moniteur_(programmation)

Comment: Yes, people frequently say "monitor" when they mean "mutex."  It's because real computer science-y monitors were in vogue at the time when Java was invented, and the Java designers expected that many Java objects would be implemented as real monitors (i.e., as objects whose methods were _all_ `synchronized`).  Fortunately they didn't _force_ us to write that way, but anyway, the name "monitor" became part of the vocabulary of Java.

Comment: @jameslarge - People who do that don't understand that "monitor" and "mutex" are actually different.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, monitor and mutex do not mean the same thing.

- A mutex is effectively a synonym for a lock; i.e. a *"synchronization device commonly used to establish mutual exclusion"*.
- A monitor combines the semantics of a mutex with a mechanism for signaling and waiting on a condition.

References:

- Wikipedia page on ["Mutual exclusion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)
- Wikipedia page on ["Lock (computer science)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science))
- Wikipedia page on ["Monitor (synchronization)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization))

Note that these articles include various references to CS literature which will help to give the historical context for the use of these terms in Computer Science.

---

Having said that, these two terms are often (incorrectly) treated as interchangeable.